# Django Ordering by a specific ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

the following structure is given:

```py
class MovieTranslation:
  lang=CharField()
  title=CharField()

class Movie:
  key = CharField()
  movie_translations = ManyToManyField(MovieTranslation)
```

Now for example, for english users I want to sort by the english `MovieTranslation` of a `Movie`?
I want to use it in a `ViewSet` as a `Filterset` class.

I think it should be something like `order_by(movie_translations__name='en'__title)`. The last part of course doesn't work. I found solutions, for filtering before, but I do not think filtering for english Translations work, since then I get a list of Movie Objects who have an english Title, but could still have other languages. I want to sort specifically by the field of a manytomany field.

So is there a way to order by a specific `ManyToMany` Instance (i.e. all `MovieTranslations` where the name is 'en' ) ?

I was thinking about annotate, but had the same problems

I am thinking now that maybe joining with a specific `ManyToMany` field could work.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
Movie.objects
  .filter(movie_translations__title='en')
  .order_by('movie_translations__title')
```

**Please note** that it assumes that all movies have english translation. The SQL query produced by ORM uses `INNER JOIN` which will filter out movies that have no translation with `title=en`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Movie.MovieTranslation.filter(lang="en").order_by("-title")
```